# carriage return symbol, new command

Tags: errors

When I define this:

```
\newcommand{\return}{\raisebox{1.2pt}{\setlength{\fboxsep}
  {2pt}\ovalbox{$\hookleftarrow$} }}
```

In output compiler types:

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \setlength {\fboxsep }{2pt}\ovalbox {$\hookleftarrow $}
```

My packages:

```
\documentclass[russian,utf8,simple,hpadding=5mm]{eskdtext}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pscyr}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. The macro `\ovalbox` is provided by the package [`fancybox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancybox), so you need `\usepackage{fancybox}` to use it.

Comment: May I suggest you have a ready-to-use carriage return symbol `mathabx`, called through the `\dlsh` command?

Comment: Note that your quoting of the error message must be wrong, the message tells you always that the command that is undefined is the last thing on the first line of the message.  If you look in the log `\ovalbox` must be at the _end_ of the line

Answer (score 10):

To visualize keystrokes you could use either the [`keystroke`](http://ctan.org/pkg/keystroke) or the [`menukeys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{keystroke}
\usepackage{menukeys} 
\begin{document}
\verb|\Return| \Return % from package keystroke

\verb|\keys{\return}| \keys{\return} % from package menukeys
\end{document}
```

> [image]